# Leaflet layer moves separately from map when zooming

Tags: leaflet, html5-canvas

I've built a map with a GeoJSON layer that shows some countries of the world as filled-in polygons.

[image]

Everything is working fine, except that when you zoom into the map, the layer sometimes moves separately from the map. The problem is more pronounced on mobile, and my gifs below are from mobile.

[image]

Related questions I've looked at but don't quite apply to this case:

- [Leaflet shapes move when zooming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64890232/leaflet-shapes-move-when-zooming)
- [LeafletJS markers move on zoom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17875438/leafletjs-markers-move-on-zoom)

There are also related issues in the Leaflet GitHub ([Map content moves when zooming](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/4053) and [Strange zooming behaviour with vector (extended L.geoJson) layers on 1.0.0](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/4247)), but the solution to that problem was to update the CSS file so that its version was in sync with the JS file. I'm using [react-leaflet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-leaflet) with the CSS from [leaflet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/leaflet) which are in sync to the best of my knowledge.

I also see this problem happening on [the GeoJSON example](https://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson) on the Leaflet website:

[image]

Reproducible code is at https://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson/. The more things there are on the layer, the greater this slippage. Sometimes when zooming I accidentally grab onto the layer with one finger and it stays underneath that finger as the map gets panned. It is not limited to GeoJSON - it occurs with CircleMarkers as well ([example site I found online where it occurs](https://cymraeg.ling.cam.ac.uk/?map=6)).

How can we stop this slipping effect and make the features more "anchored" like on Google Maps?

Comment: Steps to reproduce: put 1 finger on a path/vector feature, start panning a little bit, then (while first finger still down) put a 2nd finger and start zooming in or out, then release all fingers.

Comment: Strangely visible only the 1st time in Leaflet version 1.6.0: https://plnkr.co/edit/bHjrrQxycoaJOyBw Same since version 1.0.0-beta.1: https://plnkr.co/edit/nwj6IIknhAlfTyPk Symptom slightly different on version 0.7.7 https://plnkr.co/edit/W9TWjIcQQUJXZBRM (slip during zoom only)

Comment: Reported in Leaflet issues as [#7680](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/7680). Actually a duplicate of [Leaflet #6395](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/6395). Currently no full fix implemented, but some partial workarounds are described.